# Sum data from two data frames matched by rowname

Tags: r, dataframe, function, operators

I have two data frames with different numbers of rows, thus:

```
df1:
           Data1
2019-03-01 0.011
2019-04-01 0.021
2019-05-01 0.013
2019-06-01 0.032
2019-07-01 NA

df2:
           Data2
2019-01-01 0.012
2019-02-01 0.024
2019-03-01 0.033
2019-04-01 0.017
2019-05-01 0.055
2019-06-01 0.032
2019-07-01 0.029
```

The row names are dates. I want to add a second column, "Result", to df1. This column would sum the value in df1$Data1 + the value in the row of df2$Data2 with the same row name. (The row names in both data frames are unique and ordered.) So, for example:

```
df1$Result[1] <- df1$Data1[1] + df2$Data2[3]
```

The result would be:

```
df1:
           Data1 Result
2019-03-01 0.011 0.044
2019-04-01 0.021 0.038
2019-05-01 0.013 0.068
2019-06-01 0.032 0.064
2019-07-01 NA    NA
```

The only way I can figure out how to do this is with a looping construct, but I think there is a better way. I'm not finding it, though, so I imagine I'm looking for the wrong thing. Any ideas?

I am also open to other suggestions for getting to the same end. So, for example, if this would be easier to accomplish with the dates in a data column instead of in the row name, that would be fine. Or if it would be easier to do with a ts object, although I generally find data frames easier to work with.

Comment: You've already got a working answer. I'd, however, suggest that you use those dates as a date columns, instead of rownames, as it makes it easier to use them afterwards, in case you need

Comment: The working answer only works one row at a time, though. Is there a way to make it work thousands of lines at a time, using only the rowname (or value in the date column) to match rows?

Comment: I was referring to @Ronak's answer, which works already

Comment: Ah! My mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `merge` the two dataframes by rownames and then add the corresponding columns

```
transform(merge(df1, df2, by = 0), sum = Data1 + Data2)


#   Row.names Data1 Data2   sum
#1 2019-03-01 0.011 0.033 0.044
#2 2019-04-01 0.021 0.017 0.038
#3 2019-05-01 0.013 0.055 0.068
#4 2019-06-01 0.032 0.032 0.064
#5 2019-07-01    NA 0.029    NA
```

Or similarly with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

inner_join(df1 %>% rownames_to_column(), 
           df2 %>% rownames_to_column(), by = "rowname") %>%
mutate(Result = Data1 + Data2)
```

Comment: Thanks! Both of these solutions create a third data frame with the data from df1, the data from df2, and the sum. What I want to do is add a new column to df1 with the sum. But this does seem to work: df1$Result <- transform(merge(df1, df2, by = 0), sum = Data1 + Data2)$sum . Does that look right to you?

Comment: @Bolio The third dataframe already has the same number of rows as df1 right ? You just need to select relevant columns. So let's say the third dataframe is `df3`, you can select columns by `df3[c(1, 2, 4)]` which would be equivalent of adding new column to `df1`. Also the approach you have used should be fine as well and should give you the expected output.

Comment: I've discovered a catch. In my example above, df1 contained a subset of the rows in df2. In my actual use case, df1 and df2 are of different lengths but only partially overlap. This seems to break things. Info added above.

Comment: Thank you, @Ronak. In the process of writing a new question, I found the answer: the "all.x = TRUE" argument to merge.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, keep.rownames = TRUE)
setDT(df2, keep.rownames = TRUE)
df2[df1, on = .(rn)][, sum := Data1 + Data2][]
#           rn Data2 Data1   sum
#1: 2019-03-01 0.033 0.011 0.044
#2: 2019-04-01 0.017 0.021 0.038
#3: 2019-05-01 0.055 0.013 0.068
#4: 2019-06-01 0.032 0.032 0.064
#5: 2019-07-01 0.029    NA    NA
```